# How can I dynamically repeat grid-template-areas

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a site on Wordpress and a section where the user adds any number of photos. The section is made with grid. Now the problem is that by default there are 10 photos in the section. But when the user adds more, the grid breaks. How can I make the grid repeat?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-areas: "one two three four five" "six six seven seven eight" "nine ten seven seven eight";
}

.grid .grid-item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}

.grid .grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: two;
}

.grid .grid-item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: three;
}

.grid .grid-item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: four;
}

.grid .grid-item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: five;
}

.grid .grid-item:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: six;
}

.grid .grid-item:nth-child(7) {
  grid-area: seven;
}

.grid .grid-item:nth-child(8) {
  grid-area: eight;
}

.grid .grid-item:nth-child(9) {
  grid-area: nine;
}

.grid .grid-item:nth-child(10) {
  grid-area: ten;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use grid areas if you want to have a repeating behavior. Simply define the number of columns or rows. I wrote a detailed article about such technique: https://css-tricks.com/exploring-css-grids-implicit-grid-and-auto-placement-powers/

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 30px;
}
.grid > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.grid .grid-item:nth-child(10n + 6) {
  grid-column: 1/span 2;
}
.grid .grid-item:nth-child(10n + 7) {
  grid-column: 3/span 2;
}
.grid .grid-item:nth-child(10n + 7),
.grid .grid-item:nth-child(10n + 8) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 11</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 12</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 13</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 14</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 15</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 16</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 17</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 18</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 19</div>
  <div class="grid-item">GridItem 20</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When adding pictures, the next 10 pictures occupy a different number of rows than the first 10. Is it related to the size of the pictures? When you set them to fixed sizes, they still do not shrink as much as the first 10

Comment: @yanksi_ as you can see they don't take extra row but the height of the rows is bigger. You need to fix the height of the rows using grid-auto-rows

Comment: Can grid-auto-rows be responsive? The default height is 360px. I need it to change in proportion to the picture when the screen is compressed, and not remain 360px. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Now I made grid-auto-rows: 360px and when adaptive, the height remains 360px and the image remains the same height

Comment: @yanksi_ use the vw unit